# Remove elements of a list explicitly

Tags: r, list

I have this list:

```
myList <- list(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10))

names(myList) <- c("one", "two", "three")

$one
 [1] -0.07587506 -0.09997924 -0.41846732  1.41542651 -0.58678093  0.56909465 -1.11074541
 [8]  1.94663786  0.46381799 -0.11458166

$two
 [1]  0.98883679 -0.06305794 -0.78961229  1.21091484  0.19636700  0.27458057  0.12374154
 [8]  0.83782946 -0.79627870  0.97675486

$three
 [1]  0.67033455 -0.80243815  0.08716750 -2.90455146 -0.02433571 -0.93062428 -0.16886116
 [8] -0.60927976 -1.77758270 -1.05033148
```

I want to remove `two` and `three` from the list and I want to refer to these elements using "two" and "three". I've tried:

```
myList <- myList[[-c("two", "three")]]
```

...which gives an error.

How can I remove `two` and `three` from the list and refer them using "two" and "three"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
myList[which(names(myList) %in% c("two","three"))] <- NULL
```

Comment: This is easier to understand, if you try to delete them on at a time:
`myList[2] <- NULL; myList$three <- NULL`.

Comment: or just `myList[c("two", "three")] <- NULL`.