# How to delete an element from a list of strings in R

Tags: r, string, list

Among a few less relevant others, I checked these two answers:
[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652136/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-a-list)
[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778161/remove-elements-of-a-list-explicitly)

However, the solutions presented there did not help.

I am probably misunderstanding my own problem and trying to do the right thing the wrong way. I appreciate any help.

I have the following code where I build a list of strings and try to delete the second element of the list:

```
> my_strings <- "string1 string2 string3 string4 string5"
> my_list <- strsplit(my_strings,split=" ")
> #Now trying to delete one element from my_list using positive indexing
>
> my_list[[2]] <- NULL #does not work
> my_list[2] <- NULL #nope. Doesn't work either
> my_list[[1]][2] <- NULL #error: replacement has length zero
> my_list[[1]][[2]] <- NULL # error: more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

So, my question is: how can I delete the second element (or multiple elements, like 1 and 3) of my_list? The elements of my_list are not named, I want to access them by the numeric index.

Comment: `mylist[[1]] <- mylist[[1]][-2]`.  I'd suggest reading a bit on the way subsetting and lists work in R.

Comment: Take-home message: Use subsetting instead of assigning `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you very much Justin (and Roland). Using the line you showed with a range instead of the negative index works perfectly for my purposes. I was trying to remove the items with the "<- NULL" construct, but it does not work. Subsetting and then overwriting the list works perfectly and the result is the same. So I guess I cannot simply remove elements, but I rather have to subset the list and replace it with the smaller list

Comment: Subsetting sure works great to work on a list of strings. You can use ranges either with positive indices (`mylist[[1]][3:7]` keeps elements 3 to 7) or negative indices (`mylist[[1]][-3:-7]` discards elements 3 to 7). Thank you again!

Comment: Update: Variables for range of indices DO work, but you have to guarantee that 'both' indices are either negative or positive. For example, `mylist[[1]][var1:var2]` will work only if both indices are either positive or negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you intended to create a list of vectors with your code; might be easier to just use a character vector. Try using unlist first:

```
my_list <- unlist(strsplit(my_strings,split=" "))

my_list <- my_list[-2]
```

Comment: Ah, okay. Than @Justin's answer is best.

Comment: Your answer works fine, but I have to use list() again in the second line, otherwise I end up with something that is not a list. However, the subsetting option presented by Justin and Roland caught my eye better. I accepted your answer though, since they only added comments.

Comment: Yup, I misspoke -- sorry for the confusion! But again, sounds like @Justin's solution took care of your needs.