# How can one crop specific elements in a multi-level list in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know of a way to crop a multi-level list in R? I have several levels (e.g. attributes "alive", "age", "color") for each element of my list. I would like to crop the list to only contain elements where e.g. `x$color=="blue"`:

#### Example

```
set.seed(1)
ind <- vector(mode="list", 20)
for(i in seq(ind)){
    ind[[i]]$alive <- 1
    ind[[i]]$age <- 0
    ind[[i]]$color <- c("blue", "red")[round(runif(1)+1)]
}

keep <- which(sapply(ind, function(x) x$color) == "blue")
keep
#[1]  1  2  5 10 11 12 14 16 19

ind[[keep]] # doesn't work
#Error in ind[[keep]] : recursive indexing failed at level
```

Cropping, or setting to `NULL`, seems possible for a list with a single level, as is shown in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16778213/1199289), but does not work for my multi-level list.

Comment: `ind[keep]` should work

Comment: @JakeBurkhead - excellent. I guess I still have some ground to cover in understanding the subtleties of brackets `[]` in R. Feel free to write this up an an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ind[keep]` is what you're looking for.

From `?'[['`:

`The most important distinction between ‘[’, ‘[[’ and ‘$’ is that the ‘[’ can select more than one element whereas the other two select a single element.`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use `Filter`, and cut out the `which` step.

```
Filter(function(x) x$color == 'blue', ind)
```